# Monotone/ desaturated reflection material in Blender/ Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, reflection

Does anybody know how to get desaturated reflection (monotone) made from colorful object? Blue object, white plane beneath. With standard settings the reflection is blue. I would like to have it black and white. I tried adding HUE/SATURNATION node to diffuse or glossy shader (connected into mix shader) but this doesn't seem to work… I know it's possible with compositing but it's a bit tedious…. Any idea? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Light Path node* in your colored object's material.
Then, the object's reflections will be monochromatic.

Connect the *Is Reflection Ray output* into the *FAC input* of a mix shader.

[image]

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that is is done in the reflected object shaders, not in the reflective object. Wonder if there is any way to achieve the same effect only through the glossy material

Comment: Thank you, that's good direction. This solution however works fine with with gray surface/ gray background etc. Is there a way to achieve good monochrome reflection with white surface and white environmental background? Something like multiply effect in Photoshop etc... With this set-up it kind of disappears… Thanks for reply once again!

Comment: @pablographix Hello :). White surfaces give just faint reflections - that's just physics. I'll check later today, if there's a way around it.

Comment: But i think the Compositor would be a good tool - you can mix layers there like in Photoshop (multiply, overlay, etc...) :).

Comment: The only work-around I've found so far is setting a plane as "Shadow catcher" (object/ visibility/ shadow catcher), rendering an object on transparency (separate layer), rendering the entire scene on another layer and than compositing everything together in compositor. Is works, however this "shadow catcher" option simply catches shadows (no reflection), so final result looks like "back from the 90'ties" ;). It would be nice if Blender developers consider adding simple "multiply" option - I mean physics working for multiply effect like in Adobe etc...

Comment: And here I was, using the compositor with Cryptomatte and multiple render layer (because of volumetrics) to achieve the same effect … thanks!

Comment: @RomualdBrunet Glad to hear it's useful to others :). Good luck with your project.